# Java Mail Attachment with FileSystemResource from a URL: "FileNotFoundException"

Tags: java, email

I'm using Java Mail to send an email with attachments. The attachments are not stored locally under the application, but rather pulled dynamically from URLs.

```
    List<FileSystemResource> fileSystemResources = new ArrayList<FileSystemResource>();
    fileSystemResources.add(new FileSystemResource(
             "http://myapp-dev.host.com/app/File1.PDF"));

    //... Prepare email with dynamic-URL-obtained attachments...
    MimeMessage msg = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, "UTF-8");
    for (FileSystemResource fileSystemResource : fileSystemResources) {
            message.addAttachment(fileSystemResource.getFilename(), fileSystemResource);
    }

    //... at the end, send
    mailSender.send(msg);
```

**The resource exists and I can verify it independently:**
example,
`http://myapp-dev.host.com/app/File1.PDF`

However I get the following exception thrown:

```
java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: 
  Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myapp-dev.host.com/app/File1.PDF 
    (No such file or directory);
```

Most examples I've seen use `FileSystemResource` for local files but not URI resources. Is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaDoc of [`FileSystemResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html) says:

> Resource implementation for java.io.File and java.nio.file.Path handles with a file system target. Supports resolution as a File and also as a URL.

It handles `file://` URLs only, not HTTP URLs.

For any URLs (both HTTP and `file://`) you can use [`UrlResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html):

> Resource implementation for java.net.URL locators. Supports resolution as a URL and also as a File in case of the "file:" protocol.